# serving javascript libraries from CDN vs combining them as one and serving as a single http connection

Tags: javascript, http, pagespeed

This is a question about improving the page-speed.

When you are given the following scenarios, which one to go with?

scenario 1

you got 10 famous js libraries in the head & all being served from respected CDN repositories. ( this means possibly 10-HTTP-connections for some people)

scenario 2

you choose to combine those libraries into one single file on your own and serve them as a single file under 1-HTTP-connection

I incline towards the first one simply due to one reason:

Because those 10 libraries are the "famous" ones, the chances are they may already be in the majority of the users' browsers' cache, avoiding all 10 connections.

Does anyone say anything about this?

What I'm also curious is that when Google evals this page, would it eval assuming those 10 HTTP connections as 10, or would it factor in the fact that this is jQuery so I'm not going to use it against you!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like concatenating them all into one would be a big load, even from your own server.  You couldn't delay load one of them (via webpack, for instance) - they'd all have to be loaded up front, no matter what.

Agreed, loading them separately could take advantage of any caching (assuming they're the same versions.)

As a point of interest: HTTP2 addresses the separate files/requests problem with the server push paradigm - the idea is to use a single connection to push known files without the client having to request them, individually.

Don't know if it would work for CDN's -- might have to self-serve them to take advantage.